# Gmaps MVCArray Heatmap issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

I have a problem with MVCArray and Heatmap from Gmaps:
I have a JSON file with GPS coordinates. This data are grouped by month/year in the file. I have 27000 coordinates. 
You have to click on "play", it's load data from file every second.
When the length of the MVCArray is about 11000 , all the markers disappear from the maps. 
Do you know why ? I'm on this issue for 2 weeks

http://jsfiddle.net/mem8654L/4/

```
var map, heatmap, dataMVC;
var source = {};
var keyStore = [];
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {lat: 48.83790981, lng: 2.2971},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

   dataMVC = new google.maps.MVCArray([]);
   heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
       data: dataMVC,
       map: map
   });
}
function update(id){
    source[id].forEach(function(val){
        dataMVC.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(val.lat),    Number(val.lon)));

    });
    console.log(dataMVC.getLength());
  }  

  function play(){
      var i=-1;
      (function f(){
          i = (i + 1) ;
      if (i>keyStore.length){
          clearInterval(intervalid);
      }
      update(keyStore[i]);
      var intervalid = setTimeout(f, 1000);
  })();
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is related with *corrupted* data loaded from `fullDatagps.json` file, you could put the following checking to determine whether lat/lng values are specified:

```
 source[id].forEach(function (val) {

        if(val.lat.length == 0 || val.lon.length == 0) { 
            console.log('Incorrect lat/lng');
        }
        else {
           var curLat = Number(val.lat);
           var curLng = Number(val.lon);
           dataMVC.push(new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng));    
        }

    });
```

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to render *all* the data points where lat and lng values are specified

```js
var map, heatmap, dataMVC;
var source = {};
var keyStore = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("https://rawgit.com/guizmo51/c9c3b37c0946551a627d/raw/133be332e631b75673ffbddfd283e864ecbd184b/fullDatagps.json", function (data) {
        source = data;
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            keyStore.push(key);
        });

    });
});



function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: { lat: 48.83790981, lng: 2.2971 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });
    dataMVC = new google.maps.MVCArray([]);
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: dataMVC,
        map: map
    });
}
function update(id) {

    source[id].forEach(function (val) {


        if(val.lat.length == 0 || val.lon.length == 0) { /* lat/lng valued are missing? */
            console.log('Incorect lat/lon: (' + val.lat + ',' + val.lng + ')');
        }
        else {
           var curLat = Number(val.lat);
           var curLng = Number(val.lon);
           dataMVC.push(new google.maps.LatLng(curLat, curLng));    
        }

    });
    //console.log(dataMVC.getLength());
     document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dataMVC.getLength();
}

function play() {
    var i = -1;
    (function f() {
        i = (i + 1);
        if (i >= keyStore.length) {
            clearInterval(intervalid);
        }
        update(keyStore[i]);
        var intervalid = setTimeout(f, 1000);
    })();
}
```

```css
 html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 90%;
        }

        #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 25%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        #floating-panel {
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            left: 25%;
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            z-index: 5;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

    <button id="bouton" onclick="play();">Play</button>
    <script defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4jZqxf64-cmt0_v8UdBTq59PF60OLjMw&signed_in=true&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap"></script>
<div id='output'/>
```

Comment: Nice !!  Thanks for your help Vadim !